# Page shifts little bit up when modal is closed

Tags: css, reactjs

There is a modal on a page. whenever we open up the modal, i am setting the style of html and body to overflow hidden. When we close that modal, the entire page shifts up a little bit, not to the top.

I have tried changing the overflow properties. The same solution without any change works in firefox but not in chrome and safari. Ideal solution would be, there should be no scroll.

Comment: Give us some code examples what you did so far. Without code we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.